# Finding memory leak potentials

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, web-applications, memory-leaks

Hi I'm having a real big problem on this. Is there any tool or process that can identify memory leaks on my java webapps. Im currently using spring, hibernate, c3p0.

Comment: You can try tools like VisualVM/JProfiler/Yourkit. To analyze which of your objects are taking up memory.

Comment: I think the Catalina engine provides a Memory Leak prevention thread as well...

Comment: do you think garbage collection will resolve this problem ? thanks !

Comment: I had several memory problems with `c3p0` a long time ago and I ended up using allways server defined pools while deploying to Tomcat or Weblogic. Anyway, try to generate a java memory dump and analyze it with eclipse memory analizer. It has been very helpfull for me several times

Comment: can i have a tutorial on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try tools like VisualVM/JProfiler/Yourkit. To analyze which of your objects are taking up memory. 
VisualVM comes with JDK, however Others might need a purchase as well.

This [link](https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java) provides a clear explanation on how to detect memory leaks and resolve them.